# Solve the query using join?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a table session1 and need to find only new entries who logged in with specific id.

```
create table session1(name varchar(16),id integer);

insert into session1 values('anshu',20);
insert into session1 values('rohit',21);
insert into session1 values('anshu',21);
insert into session1 values('sonu',21);
insert into session1 values('payal',22);
insert into session1 values('anshu',22);
insert into session1 values('roch',22);
commit;
```

The Query without join for all new users who login with id 21 will be like:

```
select name from session1 where name NOT IN(Select name from session1 where id<>21);
```

The Output will be:

```
rohit
sonu
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve it using joins?

Comment: How come you need another query? BTW, don't  tag products not involved, Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: This question was asked by interviewer to solve it using joins only.

Comment: Why use joins here? There is only one table.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou There is only 1 table but it is used twice - to find people who have logged in using id 21 and have not logged in using any other id.  Perhaps an outer join could be used?

Comment: Obviously the interviewer wanted you to show an ANTI JOIN query as shown in the answers you got. This is a pattern sometimes used on DBMS that are really slow on NOT IN and NOT EXISTS. In Oracle or SQL Server you don't need this. It would have been a more appropriate question to ask how to solve this with a simple having clause instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one table so there is nothing to join on.

In your current query you have no need to use a sub query .Your query should be :

```
select name from session1 where id <>21
```

To find ***"I have a table session1 and need to find only new entries who logged in with specific id."*** You can use this query :

```
select name from session1 where id in (20,21)
```

Comment: Sorry if i'm wrong but don't you need "IN (21)"? As the OP has asked for "NOT IN (<> 21)"...?

Comment: solve it using a join? Ok, here goes. select name from session1 a inner join session1 b on a.id=b.id and b.id<>'21'

Comment: Both queries return 4 rows, i.e. not the same result as OP's query.

Comment: You only need IN (21) if you are using mulitple values as in IN(21, 22,23) , if you are only looking for one , then you can use  =21 or <>21 , depending on what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
select s1.name
from session1 s1
  left join session1 s2 on s1.name = s2.name and s1.id <> s2.id
where s1.id = 21
  and s2.id is null
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select *
SQL&from session1 s1
SQL&  left join session1 s2 on s1.name = s2.name and s1.id <> s2.id
SQL&where s1.id = 21
SQL&  and s2.id is null;
name                      id name                      id
================ =========== ================ ===========
rohit                     21 -                          -
sonu                      21 -                          -

                  2 rows found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.name 
from session1 a 
    left join session1 b 
    on a.name=b.name 
         and b.id =21 
where b.name is null
```

Comment: Should be IS NULL instead of = NULL. Returns payal and
roch if corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need do joins, if interviewer tell you do stupid things to prove you are fit for the job, you should find another job.

Also your query is wrong

Here you have doble negation so this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM session1
WHERE NAME NOT IN (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM session1
        WHERE id <> 21
        );
```

Is equivalent to

```
SELECT NAME
FROM session1
WHERE id = 21;
```

And neither will produce your question ouput

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that if i understand correctly what you mean:

```
SELECT S1.name FROM session1 S1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT name, id FROM session1 WHERE id = 21) S2
ON S1.id = S2.id
WHERE S2.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: There's no s2.id since you don't select that column in the sub-query.

Comment: @jarlh Correct, fixed it.